# Find $ \cot\left(\sum_{n=1}^{23} \cot^{-1} (1+\sum_{k=1}^n 2k )\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, inverse-function, telescopic-series

Find the value of 
$$ \cot\left(\sum_{n=1}^{23} \cot^{-1} (1+\sum_{k=1}^n 2k )\right)$$

I tried to simplify it but it became messy. How can I find $\sum_{n=1}^{23} \cot^{-1} (1+n+n^2)$? Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint.

Use $$\arctan(n+1)-\arctan{n}=arccot(n^2+n+1)$$ and the telescopic summation.

Comment: Thanks.I have done the problem by the hint . But can I ask for the motivation behind this key observation?

Comment: I looked for a possibility to use the telescopic sum and it turned out,